# VBA - Global Variable Scope?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm struggling here a bit.

I had created a few Public variables on a form (MainForm).  I now realize I need to expand the scope of some of these variable to additional forms.

So, I moved the Public declarations to a new Module called "Globals".

When I attempt to run the new form, I am getting a complaint about an ambiguous variable as I attempt to reset its value to "".  No complaint from the "MainForm" using the same variables.

Module "Globals"

```
Public myIP As String
Public myStatus As String
```

New Form:

```
myStatus = ""   << throws an err
```

Am I correct to move the Public variable declarations to a Module?

Any thoughts about the "ambiguous variable" err from that new Form??

Thanks!

Comment: Public variables should be declared in modules. When declared on form it becomes the property of the form and can be access via formname.property. [Scope of Variables](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/variable-scope-lifetime.htm)

Comment: Agree.  So, moving the module "Globals" should expand the scope.

But, I am left struggling with the the ambiguous variable name err when I attempt to reset the value of that variable.  I am not re-declaring that variable in the new form.

Comment: Calling the variable via the form reference does work, but seems cumbersome:  Forms!MainForm.myStatus

Comment: Declaring the variables as 

"Global myStatus as string"

Seems to address my need.  Is this correct?

Comment: "ambiguous variable" error occurs bcoz of more than one variable with same name within same module. These errors can be easily identified by clicking on Debug > Compile VBA Project on standard toolbar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be trying to declare the same variable in the same scope. See [here](http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=221738) for more details, also a SO thread related to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3266584/referencing-global-variable-ms-access).

As a side note, I notice with Excel VBA you must [appropriately qualify](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/scope.aspx) a module-level variable if a procedure-level variable is declared with the same name.